# Problema con la validación correcta de un formulario con Javascript

Tags: javascript, formularios, validación

mi problema es el siguiente: Cuando envias el formulario con los datos mal, o vacío, tira el error correctamente. Cuando lo completas se envía correctamente, y si vuelvo (con los campos vacíos) a darle click en envíar sigue saliendo el cartel de "envíado correctamente", y no se corrige hasta actualizar la página. El problema es que la function para aplciar la clase verde de validación debe cumplir la condición del if, lo cual hace y funciona, pero si ya validó y el formulario tiene un reset, por que razón si vuelvo a dar click en enviar de nuevo se validan los imputs vacíos sin cumplirse la condición del if??
No encuentro ninguna falla en la sintaxis.

```
const expresiones = {
    nombre: /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s]{1,40}$/,
    apellido: /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s]{1,30}$/,
    correo: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/,
    telefono: /^\d{8,14}$/,
    mensaje: /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9_.-@\s].{3,150}$/
};

const campos = {
    nombre: false,
    apellido: false,
    correo: false,
    telefono: false,
    mensaje: false
};

const inputNombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
const inputApellido = document.getElementById("apellido");
const inputCorreo = document.getElementById("correo");
const inputTelefono = document.getElementById("telefono");
const inputMensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");

const formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

const validarNombre = (evento) => {
    console.log("Se soltó una tecla");

    if (expresiones.nombre.test(evento.target.value)) {
        console.log("El dato esta correcto");

        document.querySelector("#grupo_nombre i").classList.remove("icono_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_nombre input").classList.remove("formulario_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_nombre p").classList.remove("formulario_input_error_activo");

        campos.nombre = true;
    }

    else {
        console.log("El dato esta incorrecto");

        document.querySelector("#grupo_nombre i").classList.add("icono_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_nombre input").classList.add("formulario_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_nombre p").classList.add("formulario_input_error_activo");

        campos.nombre = false;
    }
};

const validarApellido = (evento) => {
    console.log("Se soltó una tecla");

    if (expresiones.apellido.test(evento.target.value)) {
        console.log("El dato esta correcto");

        document.querySelector("#grupo_apellido i").classList.remove("icono_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_apellido input").classList.remove("formulario_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_apellido p").classList.remove("formulario_input_error_activo");

        campos.apellido = true;
    }

    else {
        console.log("El dato esta incorrecto");

        document.querySelector("#grupo_apellido i").classList.add("icono_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_apellido input").classList.add("formulario_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_apellido p").classList.add("formulario_input_error_activo");

        campos.apellido = false;
    }
};

const validarCorreo = (evento) => {
    console.log("Se soltó una tecla");

    if (expresiones.correo.test(evento.target.value)) {
        console.log("El dato esta correcto");

        document.querySelector("#grupo_correo i").classList.remove("icono_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_correo input").classList.remove("formulario_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_correo p").classList.remove("formulario_input_error_activo");

        campos.correo = true;
    }

    else {
        console.log("El dato esta incorrecto");

        document.querySelector("#grupo_correo i").classList.add("icono_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_correo input").classList.add("formulario_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_correo p").classList.add("formulario_input_error_activo");

        campos.correo = false;
    }
};

const validarTelefono = (evento) => {
    console.log("Se soltó una tecla");

    if (expresiones.telefono.test(evento.target.value)) {
        console.log("El dato esta correcto");

        document.querySelector("#grupo_telefono i").classList.remove("icono_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_telefono input").classList.remove("formulario_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_telefono p").classList.remove("formulario_input_error_activo");

        campos.telefono = true;
    }

    else {
        console.log("El dato esta incorrecto");

        document.querySelector("#grupo_telefono i").classList.add("icono_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_telefono input").classList.add("formulario_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_telefono p").classList.add("formulario_input_error_activo");

        campos.telefono = false;
    }
};

const validarMensaje = (evento) => {
    console.log("Se soltó una tecla");

    if (expresiones.mensaje.test(evento.target.value)) {
        console.log("El dato esta correcto");

        document.querySelector("#grupo_mensaje i").classList.remove("icono_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_mensaje textarea").classList.remove("formulario_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_mensaje p").classList.remove("formulario_input_error_activo");

        campos.mensaje = true;
    }

    else {
        console.log("El dato esta incorrecto");

        document.querySelector("#grupo_mensaje i").classList.add("icono_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_mensaje textarea").classList.add("formulario_input_con_error");
        document.querySelector("#grupo_mensaje p").classList.add("formulario_input_error_activo");

        campos.mensaje = false;
    }
};

inputNombre.addEventListener("keyup", validarNombre);
inputApellido.addEventListener("keyup", validarApellido);
inputCorreo.addEventListener("keyup", validarCorreo);
inputTelefono.addEventListener("keyup", validarTelefono);
inputMensaje.addEventListener("keyup", validarMensaje);

inputNombre.addEventListener("blur", validarNombre);
inputApellido.addEventListener("blur", validarApellido);
inputCorreo.addEventListener("blur", validarCorreo);
inputTelefono.addEventListener("blur", validarTelefono);
inputMensaje.addEventListener("blur", validarMensaje);

formulario.addEventListener("submit", (evento) => {
    evento.preventDefault();
    
    if (campos.nombre && campos.apellido && campos.correo && campos.telefono && campos.mensaje) {
        console.log("Los datos estan correctos");

        document.getElementById("formulario_mensaje_correcto").classList.add("formulario_mensaje_correcto_activo");

        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("formulario_mensaje_correcto").classList.remove("formulario_mensaje_correcto_activo");
        }, 5000);

        console.log("Se envio el formulario");

        formulario.reset();
    }
    else {
        console.log("Los datos estan incorrectos");
        
        document.getElementById("formulario_mensaje").classList.add("formulario_mensaje_error_activo");

        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("formulario_mensaje").classList.remove("formulario_mensaje_error_activo");
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <title>Formulario de Contacto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <form action="" method="post" class="formulario" id="formulario">
            <!--  Grupo titulo  -->
            <div class="formulario_grupo" id="grupo_titulo">
                <div class="formulario_grupo_titulo">
                    <h1 class="titulo">Formulario de contacto <i class="fas fa-file-signature"></i></h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--  Grupo nombre  -->
            <div class="formulario_grupo" id="grupo_nombre">
                <div class="formulario_grupo_input">
                    <i class="fas fa-user icono_input"></i>
                    <input type="text" class="formulario_input" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre">
                </div>
                <p class="formulario_input_error">El nombre solo puede tener letras, espacios y debe tener un entre 1 y 40 caracteres</p>
            </div>

            <!--  Grupo apellido  -->
            <div class="formulario_grupo" id="grupo_apellido">
                <div class="formulario_grupo_input">
                    <i class="fas fa-user icono_input"></i>
                    <input type="text" class="formulario_input" name="apellido" id="apellido" placeholder="Ingrese su apellido">
                </div>
                <p class="formulario_input_error">El apellido solo puede tener letras, espacios y debe tener un entre 1 y 30 caracteres</p>
            </div>

            <!--  Grupo correo  -->
            <div class="formulario_grupo" id="grupo_correo">
                <div class="formulario_grupo_input">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope icono_input"></i>
                    <input type="text" class="formulario_input" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su correo">
                </div>
                <p class="formulario_input_error">El correo solo puede tener letras, numeros, puntos, guiones y guion bajo</p>
            </div>

            <!--  Grupo telefono  -->
            <div class="formulario_grupo" id="grupo_telefono">
                <div class="formulario_grupo_input">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone-alt icono_input"></i>
                    <input type="text" class="formulario_input" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Ingrese su numero de telefono">
                </div>
                <p class="formulario_input_error">El telefono solo puede tener numeros y debe tener un entre 8 y 14 digitos</p>
            </div>

            <!--  Grupo mensaje  -->
            <div class="formulario_grupo" id="grupo_mensaje">
                <div class="formulario_grupo_input">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit icono_input"></i>                   
                    <textarea rows="5" class="formulario_input input_mensaje" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" placeholder="Ingrese su mensaje o comentario aqui..."></textarea>
                </div>
                <p class="formulario_input_error">El mensaje debe tener por lo menos 4 caracteres y un maximo de 150 caracteres</p>
            </div>

            <!-- Mensaje de obligatorio -->
            <div class="formulario_grupo" id="grupo_mensaje_obligatorio">
                <div class="formulario_grupo_mensaje_obligatorio">
                    <p class="formulario_mensaje_obligatorio" id="formulario_mensaje_obligatorio" style="text-align: left;margin-left: 80px;">                        
                       (*) Todos los datos son obligatorio.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Mensaje de error -->
            <div class="formulario_grupo" id="grupo_mensaje_error">
                <div class="formulario_grupo_mensaje_error">
                    <p class="formulario_mensaje" id="formulario_mensaje">
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                        <b>Error:</b>
                        Por favor complete el formulario correctamente
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--  Grupo mensaje correcto  y boton -->
            <div class="formulario_grupo" id="grupo_boton">
                <div class="formulario_grupo_boton">
                    <button type="submit" class="formulario_btn">Enviar</button>
                </div>
                <p class="formulario_mensaje_correcto" id="formulario_mensaje_correcto">
                    El formulario ha sido enviado correctamente
                </p>
            </div>
            
        </form>
    </main>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c019168c89.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el html por favor.

Comment: Hola, ya lo agregué, gracias por revisar el código, si encontrás el problema te agradecería la ayuda.

Comment: Ya me aparecio tu error, vere que puedo hacer

Comment: Y por cierto porque simplemente no usar la propiedad `required` en el input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente estuve intentando otras formas pero al final solo valide el `value` asi:

```
if (nombre.value && apellido.value && correo.value && telefono.value && mensaje.value)
```

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/Zn4WByHQ9hk1x8WyP8)

Comment: Ya lo probé, casi funciona pero no, osea el error se corrige.... si yo pongo todos los campos con texto se envía el formulario correctamente, y luego si vuelvo a tocar con los campos vacíos sale el cartel de error, lo que yo quería arreglar se arregla, pero si yo completo mal un campo, por ejemplo pongo un @ o dejo vacío alguno sin llenar, se envía correctamente igual el formulario. es que no viste todo el código js, yo solo subí la function de tipo submit.